# Using prefetch_related() in Django in combination with raw_id_fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to eliminate queries by `prefetch_related()`. In the admin with TabularInline this works in all cases, except the ForeignKeyRawIdWidget created by `raw_id_fields = ('article',)`. This is due to the `Queryset.get()` it does, and filter actions are not supposed to work when prefetching. So for every row in the inline I'll get a seperate query.

This blogpost illustrates a workaround:
https://blog.mounirmesselmeni.de/2017/02/06/accessing-prefetched-objects-inside-your-models-methods/

The workaround looks quite messy to me, and won't work in this case since the widget does the get. Is there some proper way to do prefetching here or is this a Django prefetching limitation? Not using `raw_id_fields` is not an option since the default widget does even more queries.

Also, I don't understand why filter actions do not check the prefetching cache before actually querying the database. This small step could potentially save multitudes of queries, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference: I have [raised an issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29294#comment:5) in the Django Project. The problem is acknowledged, however, a fix would be too drastic.

The workaround I used is attached to the issue and fixes the problem (Django 3.2)

**UPDATE**: I wrote an blog article about the problem and a patch to work around the problem: https://deepintodjango.com/reducing-queries-for-foreignkeys-in-django-admin-inlines